# Can't bind json string to java string

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying pass a json string to (POJO) java string, but in my controller I'm not getting that json string as a java string.

In frontend,

```jsp
<form th:action="@{/create/ads}" th:object="${createAds}" method="post">
    <div class="allWrap">
        <ul class="dropList odaberiteMarku" th:field="${brand}">

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="allWrap mt-s">
        <ul class="dropList odaberiteModel" th:field="${model}">

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create/ads", headers="Accept=application/json", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@RequestBody @ModelAttribute CreateAds ads, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "test";
    }
    System.out.println(ads.getBrand()+", "+ads.getModels());
    return "successful";
}
```

In model class

```
public class CreateAds {
    private String brand;
    private String models;
    //other variables
    //all getters and setters 
}
```

In my json file.

```
[
  {
    "brand": "Acura",
    "models": [
      "2.2CL",
      "2.3CL",
      "3.0CL",
      "TL",
      "TSX",
      "Vigor",
      "ZDX"
    ]
  }
]
```

**In frontend:** I have an external json file which is used for car manufacturer and car model based on car manufacturer. It works fine in frontend.

**In backend:** I'm trying to bind json string to normal string, like json brand string should go java brand string and models string should go java models string.

I think, I can't bind json string to java string properly that's why I'm getting null value. So how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your json doesn't contain a "models string" but `models` is an _array_ of strings. That can't be bound to a simple Java string - you'd either have to use an array/list in your POJO as well or select one of the model strings and send that single string only.

Comment: For the models, it's ok for now. But why getting null value for brand string ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with spring boot but your form doesn't seem to contain any input fields. Are you sure the "brand" value is being sent back to the server?

Comment: "brand" is dropdown which come from that json file. it should go to the server, i never work with json string seding. that's why I'm not sure the value is send to the server or not.

Comment: Well, you should be able to use your browser's developer tools to examine the post request and check what data is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

additionally to thomas' comment (sorry, I cannot comment yet):
your endpoint accepts an object of class CreateAds and you're showing the POJO declaration of a class called Ads.

Comment: Good catch, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not talk about your UI code.

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping("/create/ads")
public String submitForm(@RequestBody CreateAds ads, BindingResult result, Model model){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "test";
    }
    System.out.println(ads.getBrand()+", "+ads.getModels());
    return "successful";
}
```

**CreateAds:**

```
public class CreateAds {
private String brand;
private ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<>();

   public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
   }

   public void setBrand(String brand) {
       this.brand = brand;
   }

   public ArrayList<String> getModels() {
      return models;
   }

   public void setModels(ArrayList<String> models) {
      this.models = models;
   }
}
```

I found your JSON Object is also wrong. Please refer below JSON Object.

```
{
"brand": "Acura",
    "models": [
     "2.2CL",
     "2.3CL",
     "3.0CL",
     "TL",
     "TSX",
     "Vigor",
     "ZDX"
   ]
 }
```

I used POSTMan and tried. It's working code. Try it.

Comment: I want just one brand name, one models name which is based on brand. For that, also need arraylist or just single string? Like, you will bought a car, which is "Acura" brand and "ZDX".

Comment: If you want brand with one model name then make String for ArrayList that's fine.
But you need to change your JSON object as well.
{
"brand" : "Acura",
"models" : "Vigor"
}

If you send array to backend then how backend is going to know which one to pick for specific request that you made.
Do it make sense.

Comment: Ok, why not working for brand although it's a single string? I'm just asking.

Comment: I already told you my code that I share is working code. Use POSTMan and check. I'm not so good in UI development. If backend code work perfectly with POSTMan then you need to debug your UI code. First try whether you are able to run backend code or not?

Comment: Yes, the **brand** and **model** not send to the controller and model class. can fix this problem?